# why it doesn't match when I set color for nodes according to it's attribute?

Tags: python, networkx

According to some current answers， I tried setting color for nodes according to it's attribute. But I found that the color doesn't match its attribute and I don't know why.

The following are example dataframes: one to describe edge, and the other to describe the attribute of nodes.

edgelist

```
    source  target  weight
0    city1   city5       1
1    city2   city6       2
2    city3   city7       3
3    city4   city8       4
4    city5   city1       5
5    city6   city2       6
6    city7   city3       7
7    city8   city4       8
8    city9  city11       9
9   city10  city12      10
10  city11   city9      11
11  city12  city10      12
12   city1  city11      13
13   city2  city12      14
14   city5  city11      15
15   city6   city5      16
16   city7   city6      17
17   city8   city7      18
18   city9   city8      19
19  city10   city4      20
20  city12   city5      21
```

node_attri

```
      city type
0    city1    A
1    city2    B
2    city3    C
3    city4    D
4    city5    A
5    city6    B
6    city7    C
7    city8    D
8    city9    A
9   city10    B
10  city11    C
11  city12    D
```

And here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

path = "data/"

df = pd.read_excel(path + "example_data_for_test1.xlsx")
node_attri = pd.read_excel(path + "example_data_for_test2.xlsx")

edgelist = list(zip(df["source"], df["target"], df["weight"]))
node_attri = dict(zip(node_attri["city"], node_attri["type"]))

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_weighted_edges_from(edgelist, weight="weight")
nx.set_node_attributes(g, node_attri, "city_type")

# function for getting color list from node attribute
def attri_to_color(G, attri_name):
    attri_for_color = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(G.nodes(data=True)), orient='index')
    replace_dict = {"A": "red", "B": 'blue', "C": 'green', "D": 'purple'}
    attri_for_color["color_code"] = attri_for_color[attri_name].replace(replace_dict)
    color = attri_for_color["color_code"].tolist()
    return color

def draw_network(g):
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(40, 30))
    pos = nx.spring_layout(g, k=2.5, iterations=50)

    d = nx.degree(g)
    d = [(d[node] + 0.1) * 50 for node in g.nodes()]

    # get color list from node attribute
    colors = attri_to_color(g, "city_type")

    nx.draw(
        g,
        pos=pos,
        node_size=d,
        node_color=colors,
        with_labels=True,
        edge_color="gainsboro",
        arrows=True,
        arrowsize=5,

        alpha=0.4,
    )
    plt.show()


draw_network(g)
```

Then the result is :
[image]

Because I set `replace_dict = {"A": "red", "B": 'blue', "C": 'green', "D": 'purple'}`, for example, cities with A type should be red, but as it is shown in the picture, node colors don't match their "type" attibute.

New to networkx, maybe the question is simple. I have spent lots of time to find answers but  they helped little.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though fairly new to networkx, this is how I would approach it

```
#Create graph

g =nx.DiGraph()

#add edgelist to graph
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edgelist, 'source', "target", ["weight"])

#prepare node attributes

node_attri1=node_attri.assign(color=node_attri['type'].map(replace_dict ))
#set node attributes
nx.set_node_attributes(G, dict(zip(node_attri1["city"], node_attri1["color"])), name="color")

#plot network
colors = [v for k, v in G.nodes(data="color")]
pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, pos=pos,with_labels=True, node_color=colors)

G.nodes.data()
```

[image]

Comment: It works! I guess the difference is that you set `color` as an node antribute, and it avoids mistake. Thank you so much :)